# asp.net C# decimal formatting money

Tags: c#, asp.net, formatting, decimal

I have a decimal value stored db as "12.3456" I want it to show it to client as "12.34"

I am using the code below .

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Price", "{0:c}")%>
```

I want the format to be like this

```
12.3456 --> 12.34
```

but it's giving me this instead.

```
12.3456 --> 12.3500
```

I am not sure if I am missing something or did something wrong.

---

*UPDATE*

I end up doing with `asp:Label` instead of `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Price", "{0:c}")%>`

```
Label Price.Text = Math.Truncate(12.3456* 100) / 100).ToString();
```

which gives me:

```
12.34
```

but if the number is `12.1000` it's giving me:

```
12.1
```

I need it in the `12.10` format

Comment: i need revers of this question , in model it's public decimal amount{get;set;} but when i enter value (29.0987) i get 30 or 0.1234 i get 0.12 but i need to have exact values it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a format string of #.00 to always show to 2 decimal places.

```
Label price.Text = String.Format("{0:#.00}", 12.1000)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings

Comment: this is also giving me 12.3500 i need 12.34

Comment: Are you sure, because `Console.WriteLine("{0:#.00}", 12.3456);` is displayed as `12.35`. Are trying to round down, ie 12.34 instead of 12.35?

Comment: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Price", "{0:#.00}")%> this is what i have in repeater right and i have 12.3456 in db. It's giving me 12.3500 on the page.

Comment: Something else must be modifying your output then. This is taken from above link on formatting. `0.45678 ("0.00", en-US) -> 0.46`

Comment: Solved it by adding label control inside repeater      Label price.Text = String.Format("{0:#.00}", 12.1000) --> 12,10

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:-

```
 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Price", "{#.00}")%>
```

**EDIT:-**

I think you need the values without rounding it. You may try like this:-

```
var f = 12.3456;
f = Math.Truncate(f * 100) / 100;
```

Comment: This would round `.3456` to `.35`

Comment: this is giving me 12.3500 i need 12.34

Comment: Since i am binding a list of items as they are in code behind. I would do a foreach loop as a last resort. I would like to solve this in <% %> tags because i have lots of pages like this so i could apply this easily in all of them.

Comment: i end up doing a foreach loop in the end

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Math.Floor(12.3456*100) / 100 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

.toString(C) 'C' is for Currency.